# Multiple bindings error for generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I'm using Ninject v2.2.1.4, so I'm not sure if this is how the newer versions of ninject work.

I'm going to use a classic example of inheritance, Animal. So I have a base abstract `Animal` class and then countless implementations of `Animal`.

```
public abstract class Animal { }
public class Tiger : Animal { }
```

Now I have an `IValidator` for `Animal` that makes sure the properties are set correctly.

```
public interface IValidator<T>
{
    bool Validate(T object);
}
```

For every implementation of `Animal` (Tiger, Cat, Dog, etc..) I may or may not have an `IValidator<T>` implementation. When there isn't a validator for a specific animal, I want to use a default validator that validates the base `Animal` properties (`IValidator<Animal>`).

So here are a couple implementations of `IValidator<T>`, including the default implementation:

```
// Contains default logic for base Animal inherited by all validators
public abstract class AbstractAnimalValidator<TAnimal> : IValidator<TAnimal> where TAnimal : Animal { }
// Default implementation for IValidator when the animal doesn't have a validator. 
//This just calls the base abstract validator logic.
public DefaultAnimalValidator : AbstractAnimalValidator<Animal> { }
// Validator for a Tiger. It calls the base validate method and then validates properties specific to a Tiger.
public TigerValidator : AbstractAnimalValidator<Tiger> { }
```

Let's just assume that the Tiger is the only animal with its own validator. I would have these two bindings:

```
Bind<IValidator<Animal>>().To<DefaultAnimalValidator>();
Bind<IValidator<Tiger>>().To<TigerValidator>();
```

So now I will have logic that tries to inject a validator for the specific animal, by attempting to get an implementation, such as injecting `IValidator<Tiger>`. If it doesn't exist, it injects the default validator using `IValidator<Animal>`.

The problem is that when trying to inject `IValidator<Tiger>`, both of the above bindings match, so I get a multiple bindings found error. This is because `Tiger` inherits from `Animal`, so `Tiger` is both a `Tiger` and an `Animal`. I've come up with some hacky solutions around this, but is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the `IValidator<T>` interface? If yes, you can mark the type parameter as contravariant:

```
public interface IValidator<in T>
{
    bool Validate(T o);
}
```

It will allow you to assign an `IValidator<Animal>` to `IValidator<Tiger>`. Then you can specify all bindings explicitly:

```
Bind<IValidator<Cat>>().To<DefaultAnimalValidator>();
Bind<IValidator<Dog>>().To<DefaultAnimalValidator>();
Bind<IValidator<Tiger>>().To<TigerValidator>();
```

This approach has also one big advantage over implicit fallback to `IValidator<Animal>`. If you add another class derived from `Animal` with it's own validator and forget to add a binding, you will get a run-time error. If you use `Bind<IValidator<Animal>>().To<DefaultAnimalValidator>()`, you will get a hard to trace bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't modify the interface. I'm using FluentValidation library. Also, this is a very simplistic example. We aren't explicitly setting the bindings like this. We are using a binding generator, and do not really want to modify the logic in the binding generator. I was hoping there was a better way to structure this so that I could get the intended functionality.

Comment: @wired_in Maybe options of [Ninject contextual-binding](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) can help?